# JQuery selector with meta-character using literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector, metacharacters

I know there are a lot of threads about using meta-character in jQuery selector, but I promise this is unique. I've an html div element with meta-character in its id. Like below,

```
<body>
<div id="div2$"><h2>Click ME</h2></div>
<button>Load JQuery</button>
</body>
```

On clicking the button, I'm calling jQuery Load and invoking an AJAX call.

```
$("#div2\\$").load("something happens here");
```

No problem upto this. Just works fine.

But when I replace the selector id with a javascript literal, like below, it wouldn't work. So far I've tried

```
var metaname = "#div2\\\\$";
$(metaname).load("something happens here");
```

or

```
var metaname = "#div2\\$";
$(metaname).load("something happens here");
```

or

```
var metaname = "\x22"+"#div2\\\\$"+"\x22";
$(metaname).load("something happens here");
```

or

```
var metaname = "\x22"+"#div2\\$"+"\x22";
$(metaname).load("something happens here");
```

Any idea how can I escape a meta-character and assign it to a javascript literal and then use that literal in selector?

Comment: Works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zr4PM/

Comment: A string is a string, nothing more. Doesn't matter if it's contained in a variable or not, as long as the string is passed as an argument to the function ( and by function I mean `$()` ).

Comment: This is my bad. I was trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7KyhD/1/  and made an error at the regscript